# View a specific report on browser without prompt to log in

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer, sql-server-2012-express

I have set up a 2012 R2 MSSQL Server 2012 R2 Express with a Report Server. I would like to be able to view a report from any computer on any network without the need to log in. I went into the SQL Server Reporting Services (`http://<serverName>/Reports/`) and granted access to the report for everyone but when I use the link

`http://<serverName>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx%2fReport+project%2fStandard+report&rs:Command=Render`

it still prompts me to log in.

How can I view this specific report without the login prompt? Do I use another link to the report, or is there a better way?

Comment: Something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx ?

Comment: Have you tried storing the credentials in the Datasource within your report?  Right-click the datasource in your report, and look at the credentials.  You can change how people access the datasource from here.

Comment: @Snowlockk I have seen that but I don't understand which option to choose for the prompt not to pop up.

Comment: @bushell do you mean in the SQL Server Management Studio? I can't find that

Comment: It is available when you edit the .rdl file.  Using either Report Builder or Visual Studio.

Comment: @bushell ah, yes I have done that, but the prompt is for logging in to the server, not the database. I tested changing it right now to double-check and the same thing happens.

Comment: @bushell means you must specify the credentials in the data source in your report. 
You can create a SQL login (rather than a windows login) first from SQL Server Management Studio. Grant it access to the database with Role = DataReader and then use those credentials in the datasource in your report.

Comment: It could also be permission on reporting services itself. Try going to the reporting services web portal. http://<serverName>/Reports  (not reportserver) and see if you get a login prompt at that point. If you can see the report web page then SSRS is probably OK, if you then navigate to your report and get prompted at that point check permissions on the report and the folder the report is contained in.

If you can get to the report but get prompted at that point, click cancel. if you get an error referring to the dataset or datasource then it's permissions to the actual data.

Comment: @Canadean_AS It only prompts me to log in in the beginning (when I navigate to the reporting services web portal. Afterwards no login is required (to open a specific report). If I directly open a report though (through the link I wrote above), it prompts me to log in to the server. How can I only show the report without the need to log in to the server?

Also, I am trying to create a new login (SQL login) but when I right click on the Security "folder" in the server in SQL Server Management Studio, there is no "New" option.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like the report is probably OK. It's authentication to SSRS itself that's the issue. I don't think anonymous access is permitted to SSRS so 'users' would need at least a local windows account and that account has to granted access in SSRS.

This is a little long winded but it may help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx

Comment: @Canadean_AS yes, but which one do I use for that? As per default Windows authentication is used but it still prompts me to log in. If I choose the last option (integrated security) which uses all three packages (NTLM, Negotiate and Kerberos) then I need to set up SPN, which sounds like an overkill.